# Set Task to belong to another process in Camunda

Tags: java, camunda

I have process 1 and task 1 started for that process.
I have process 2 and task 2 started for that process.

Is it possible to set task 2 to belong to process 1?

What I tried is the following:

```
mergeTicketTasks.forEach(task -> ((TaskEntity) task).setProcessInstanceId(baseTicketId));
```

and it is updating the process instanceId of the task but when requesting a list of tasks for process instance 1 I am not getting task 2. Additionally I am not able to see task 2 in the Camunda UI anymore.

So to summarise is it possible to make a task to belong to another process?

Answer (score 0):

How about cancelling the instance of task 2 in process instance 2 and starting an instance of task 2 in process instance 1?
This can be done using the process instance modification API:
https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.17/org/camunda/bpm/engine/runtime/ProcessInstanceModificationBuilder.html

Comment: I really can't find which method from this can be of help to achieve what you are saying. And additionally will I have all the variables assigned to that task, candidate groups and the status since this task might be completed.

Comment: You cannot 'change history' / the audit trail.  You can cancel the old task, create the new token/task in the other process instance. If you need data then you need to copy it over. If the task needs to be completed then you could also complete it.